# Bitcoind could not locate RPC credentials but rpcuser and password are set

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, authentication

I installed bitoind and synced it. But when i'm trying to connect from my php website i getting: 
Unable to connect to http://user:password@my.bitoind.server.ip:18332/. 
Also when i'm trying to see password through command

`bitcoin-cli -stdinrpcpass getblockchaininfo`

it returns

`could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/blockchain/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`.

My bitcoin.conf file is setted and works nice

```
rpcuser=USER
rpcpassword=PASS
testnet=0
daemon=1
rpcport=18332
rpcallowip=*
server=1
datadir=/blockchain/.bitcoin
txindex=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to copy the contents of `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` into `/etc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` because that's what's being used when bitcoind starts on boot up. I put my user and password in that file, rebooted, and `bitcoin-cli` worked again.

Also try adding

```
bitcoin-cli -stdinrpcpass getblockchaininfo -rpcuser user -rpcpassword password
```

Comment: Also strange thing, when i trying for exaple to change rcp port by bitcoin-cli -rpcport 8332, it's like setting to 0 and returns "Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:0"

Comment: Do you want to run testnet or mainnet? 18332 is the testnet port. 8332 is mainnet. You have `testnet=0` which maybe should be `testnet=1`?

Comment: first of all i tried testnet, but it didn't work the same. You know, i solved the problem, but with not finally correct method. I used command: bitcoind --daemon -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password -txindex -rpcallowip=127.0.0.1 -rpcallowip=185.50.25.17 -rpcport=8332. It works, but i don't think this method is ok.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works when you change
rpcallowip=*
to
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1